# Отделять javascript логику от html кода

Tags: хороший-тон, html, javascript

Вопрос больше философский, читая форумы и общаясь с людьми создалось, скажем так, правило хорошего тона отделять логику от верстки и вешать обработчики, пример:

```
// хороший код
<a id="left">next</a>
$('a').click(function(){ /* some */ });

// плохой код
<a onclick="nextslide()">next</a>
function nextslide(){ /* some */ }
```

Так вот посмотрев исходники крупных сайтов, таких как vk, google, yandex, habrahabr, ebay, paypall - html буквально кишит onClick, onMouseout, onMousemove или даже чем то таким:

```
<span class="left_count_pad" onmouseover="Pads.preload('fr')" onmousedown="return Pads.show('fr', event)" onclick="return (checkEvent(event) || browser.msie6) ? true : cancelEvent(event)">
```

это из контактика. Стало интересно почему крупные сайты предпочитают именно такой стиль ну и вообще узнать Ваше мнение.

Comment: Мне кажется, что onclick это как часть самого же html. Ничего плохого в этом нет. Тем более первый вариант это же jquery библиотека.

Comment: Скорее всего просто с динамическим контентом это работает быстрее. Или же пережитки прошлого.

Comment: я лично против совмещения верстки и перехватчиков событий и вот почему:

в случае onclick в html 

 * все хэндлеры должны имень прямую  ссылку из  в global scope
 * this указывает на window
 * скриптовый контент в результате не кэшируется у юзеров.

---

в вашем примере к тому-же jquery, там есть еще моменты, вроде того что jquery использует собственную схему обработки событий.

Comment: Интересно, а я всегда думал наоборот, первый вариант плохой а второй хороший код

Comment: @bemulima значит вы нихрена не читали, даже Флэнаган говорил про ненавязчивость js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, не в самую последнюю очередь это, как ни странно, вопрос трафика. Такой подход к оформлению кода позволяет уменьшить объём загружаемых страниц. Из той же оперы .min.js версии популярных библиотек и плагинов к ним, где вообще весь код ужат в одну строчку, ибо инструменты разработчика браузера его всё равно распарсят и красиво оформят.